# Installing plugin from URL in XML doesn't move files in plugin folder

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

When I try to install a plugin using a repo I created the downloaded zip file doesn't place the files within the plugins folder correctly. They are placed outside the folder. 
For example QGIS is expecting folder/files but when the .zip file is unzipped the files are being placed directory in the /plugins directory and not inside its own directory. I am thinking this is a QGIS 3.8 issue? Is there a different format of XML to use? Below is what I am currently using:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="" ?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="lll" version="1.0" plugin_id="227">
        <description>
            <![CDATA[QGIS tool - For common GIS tasks]]>
        </description>
        <about></about>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <qgis_minimum_version>3.0</qgis_minimum_version>
        <qgis_maximum_version>3.99</qgis_maximum_version>

        <file_name>networktool.zip</file_name>
        <icon>
        </icon>
        <author_name><![CDATA[prtdonn]]></author_name>
        <download_url>http://my-site.com/somePlugin.zip</download_url>
        <uploaded_by><![CDATA[jll]]></uploaded_by>
        <create_date>2015-05-16T15:31:19.824333</create_date>
        <update_date>2015-05-15T15:31:19.824333</update_date>
        <experimental>False</experimental>
        <deprecated>False</deprecated>
        <tracker>
        </tracker>
        <repository>
        </repository>
        <tags>
            <![CDATA[development,debugging,tools,LTE]]></tags>
        <downloads>20</downloads>
        <average_vote>5</average_vote>
        <rating_votes>10</rating_votes>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```